# get text from html page with beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape this part of text, nested in that HTML page.

```
link: http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Frost

text needed: Frost's component blueprints are acquired from Lieutenant Lech Kril & Captain Vor (Exta, Ceres).
```

I used bs4 before, but I don't know how to extract this specific text in any way.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page isn't very friendly to web scraping. I made a function `get_text()` that takes two parameters, `tag_from` and `tag_to`. It will scrape all text between these two tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Frost').text, 'lxml')

def get_text(tag_from, tag_to):
    rv = ''
    while True:
        s = tag_from.next_sibling
        if s == tag_to:
            break
        if isinstance(s, NavigableString):
            rv += s
        else:
            rv += s.text
        tag_from = tag_from.next_sibling
    return rv.strip()

s = get_text(soup.select_one('#Acquisition').parent, soup.select_one('#Acquisition').parent.find_next('table'))
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
Frost's component blueprints are acquired from Lieutenant Lech Kril & Captain Vor (Exta, Ceres).
```

EDIT:

On this page this text isn't easily targetable, no tag that encapsulates it. So my method is going from one tag and building the string from all content I find along the way until the end tag.

Some of the content is of type `NavigableString` (plain text), some of the content is other tags (I get the string from these tags with `.text` property).

Comment: thanks! works like a charm! can you add a little description to what you did? so i can learn from this

Comment: @Khristian I added short description, hope it helps.